# Sync Framework on Android throws SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, microsoft-sync-framework

I am about to create an Android test client that tries to sync with a server that has MS Sync Framework running on.
I provisioned the database and created the necessary WCF files, and in the browser, my service seems okay. When I run its diagnostic method, it looks okay.

Diagnostic      Test    Result  Comments
Sync Framework Runtime:     PASSED   None 
Connection to SQL Server_   PASSED  None
Database Provisioning_      PASSED  None
Batching Folder Exists?:        N/A  Batching is not enabled. 
Write access to batching folder N/A:     Batching is not enabled. 
ClientAccessPolicy.xml/CrossDomain.xml files:   FAILED   Could not find clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml file. Silverlight clients invoking the service from another domain will be unable to make requests successfully.

Service ConfigurationSetting    Configured Value
 Scope Name:    wcfscope
 Default Conflict Resolution:   ClientWins
 Default Serialization Format:  ODataJson
 Verbose Error Response:    true
 Batching Directory:    BATCHING_NOT_ENABLED
 Download Batch Size    BATCHING_NOT_ENABLED

I downloaded the only available Android example: http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/documentation
and modified accordingly. After many hours of suffering, my Android project compiles.
When I run the application, I get the following exception.
The calling is this: 
 Uri uri = MyProviderClass.getSyncUri("WCFScopeSyncService",
          "WCFScope");
      ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
      int result = res.update(uri, null, null, null);
On the server side, no error is made in the log. What should I check?

```
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302): IOException<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302): java.net.SocketTimeoutException<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider.Sync(BaseContentProvider.java:726)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider.update(BaseContentProvider.java:517)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:235)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:990)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at com.example.testandroid.AsyncSync.doInBackground(AsyncSync.java:25)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)<br>
03-15 23:47:19.600: E/pl.selvin.android.syncframework.content.BaseContentProvider(30302):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)<br>
```

Comment: Well, I managed to download data from the sync service, and store it on my device. I just don't know how to proceed now. If I modify the data on my device, should I set its dirty bit?

Comment: no ... you should use ContentProvider update method ... it will set dirty bit for you ... do not use direct access to sqlite ...

Comment: @Selvin: Well, in the meantime I gave up using SyncFramework and I use full sync every time. Do you intend to create a full featured example? I believe you were the closest to accomplish that.